# Identify the truth-teller among truth-tellers and liars

Tags: logic, algorithms

Here is the problem:
We have n people and we know  that some of them are liars some of them are truth-tellers.The truth tellers are more than the liars.We can ask everyone whether they or another person is liar or is truth-teller.
The truth-tellers are always truthful and correct and a liar may tells the wrong answer or right answer.
How can I find who are the truth-tellers and who are the liars with asking only 2*n - 3 questions?

Comment: If you are only allowed to ask someone whether they are a truth teller you cannot succeed because the liars can also claim to be truth tellers.  You must be allowed to ask one person about another.  Please make clear what questions are allowed.  It is also usual for liars to always lie in questions like this, though there are sometimes people who cannot be relied on.  They usually get a different name from liars.

Comment: Excuse me for the mistake,I edited it.You can ask one person about another.

Comment: Are you supposed to find out what everybody is, or just find one truth teller?  I think the usual problem is just to find one.  Of course, once you find one you can find out everybody else in $n-1$ questions or less, but I doubt you can find one in $n-2$ questions.  A good place to start is to let $n=3$.  It doesn't help to ask anyone what they are, so your choices are to ask each about the person to their left, or to ask one pair about each other plus one more question.

Comment: How do you find the truth teller with n-2 questions?

Comment: For $n=3$ you can call the people $A,B,C$ and ask each about the one after them.  If they are all truth tellers they will say so and you are done.  If you have two truth tellers and one liar, say the liar is $C$.  $B$ will be called a truth teller by $A$, $C$ will be called a liar by $B$, and $A$ may be called anything.  The one who is called a truth teller and calls someone a liar is a truth teller, tells the truth about his neighbor, and the third must be a truth teller to have a majority, so you are done.

Comment: A standard trick: "If I were to ask you if you are a truth-teller, would you answer positively?"

Comment: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3586858/knights-spies-games-and-ballot-sequences) links to a paper on the problem with a full solution.